# Curves projected on object

Tags: bezier-curves, project

i am trying to do a xenomorph egg like in the pic below but i am stuck at creating the 'petals' edges to look realistic, any idea if a curve projected on the egg main is the way to go ?All i currently can do is some straight lines which i then project on the egg but no way it looks realistic.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a curve at all. Here's how I would go about a model like this.

First I would make a "sphere" by adding a subdivision surface to a cube with three subdivision levels (`CTRL+3`). I would then add a *cast modifier* and cast it as a sphere, to make the mesh a true sphere shape.

[image: Sphere]

Then I would apply the modifiers, and make the egg shape using proportional editing set to smooth.

[image: EggShape]

Then I would inset THESE faces, and scale them inwards slightly.

[image: FaceScale]

I would also scale the "seam" edges closer together on their respective axes:

[image: SeamEdges]

Then I would turn proportional editing back on, but set to random this time, making sure to check "connected only". I would then select some random vertices along the edges of the "petal seams" and scale them towards each other on whatever axis they lie. (I know the "gaps" are wider in the first image - I took this screenshot early, before I scaled the edges).

[image: Random1]

[image: Random2]

Do this for all the "seams", then select the centre areas again, and inset by a small amount.

[image: Inset1]

Do the same for the outer areas - this helps define the edges of the "petals"

[image: Inset2]

You should then be able to select the whole surround edge as one loop - you can then extrude this (extrude faces along normals) to form the lip.

[image: EggLip]

Lastly,  add another subdivision surface modifier, and shade smooth to smooth it out.

[image: EggFinal]

Hope this helps.

Comment: why not create a uv sphere the first time around instead of this step "First I would make a "sphere" by adding a subdivision surface to a cube with three subdivision levels (CTRL+3). I would then add a cast modifier and cast it as a sphere, to make the mesh a true sphere shape."

Comment: If you look at the topology of a UV sphere, the top and bottom poles are made of tri's surrounding a point. I did what I did to get a "quad only" sphere. They are often much easier to work with.